# Unable to fetch the value of a combo box

Tags: javascript, combobox, dojo

I am trying to  access the text property of the selected option of a combo box. The following code is where I have reached so far but I am not able to recognize the error in my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<style type="text/css">
table,td
{
border: 1px solid black;
}
td
{
height:30px;
vertical-align:center;
padding:15px;
}
.tableClass
{
    border:1px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<script src='dojo/dojo.js' data-dojo-config='parseOnLoad: true'></script>
<script>
//require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/form/FilteringSelect", "dojo/store/Memory"]);

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dijit.form.ComboBox");
    function alterEntries()
        {
            //alert("in");
            document.getElementById('overlayName').value = dijit.byId('stateSelect').value;

            dojo.style("description", {
                display:"block",
            });
            dojo.style("overlayName", {
                display:"block",
            });
        }
        function submitEntries(ovlName,overlayDescription)
        {
            var textOfOvl = getSelectedText(ovlName);
            alert("overlayName " + ovlName + " overlayDescription " + overlayDescription);
        }

        function getSelectedText(elementId) 
        {
            var elt = document.getElementById(elementId);

            if (elt.selectedIndex == -1)
            {
                alert("null");
                return null;
            }

            return elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].text;
        }

    </script>

</head>

<body class="claro">
    <select id="stateSelect" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ComboBox">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
        <option value="CA">California</option>
    </select>
     <input name="overlayName" type="text" value="overlayName" id="overlayName"  style="display:none">
    <textarea name="description" cols="50" rows="3" id="description" style="display:none"></textarea>
    <p>
        <button onclick="alterEntries();">EDIT</button>
        <button onclick="submitEntries(document.getElementById('overlayName').value,document.getElementById('description').value);">SUBMIT</button>
    </p>


</body>

</html>
```

I am breaking my head trying to figure out what is going wrong.Can someone please hep me out.Many thanks!

Comment: `getSelectedText(elementId)` returns selected option's text to nothing: `getSelectedText(ovlName);`. Where did you expect to see this value?

Comment: @ValeraLeontyev : I assigned it to a variable as `var textOfOvl = getSelectedText(ovlName);` . No change yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your get selected text should look like this in order to get the displayed text:

```
function getSelectedText(el){
     var text = dijit.byId(el).get('displayedValue'),
     value = dijit.byId(el).get('value');
     alert(text);
     return text;
}
```

I recomend you to check out the basic dijit tutorials, document.getElementById will yield a very different reult than dijit.byId when working with dijits.

this is also a slight correction in your input

```
 <input name="overlayName" type="hidden" value="stateSelect" id="overlayName">
```

also i recomend you to use

```
dojo.byId('textId');
```

instead of document.getElementById

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very-very strange. As I can understand it at line

`<input name="overlayName" type="text" value="overlayName" id="overlayName"  style="display:none">`

value attribute must be set to `stateSelect`, but not to `overlayName`.

And to see any working result in browser change implementation of `submitEntries` function:

```
function submitEntries(ovlName,overlayDescription)
{
    var textOfOvl = getSelectedText(ovlName);
    alert(textOfOvl);
}
```

See [working modification of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/feedbee/DEU93/).